# Prove there exist an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $V$ be a vector space and $U,W,Z$ are subspaces of $V$,  where $V=Z \oplus W=Z \oplus U$

Prove there exist linear isomorphism $f:V \to V$ such that for every $\gamma \in Z,  \ \ f(\gamma)=\gamma$ and $f(U) \subseteq W$.

Can someone give me a hint ? I know that transfomation is an isomorphism when $\ker f = \{ 0\}$ and $im f=V$

Comment: I assume $V$ is a vector space over some field $k$ and $U$ is ...?

Comment: What is $\;U\;$ ??

Comment: yes, $V$ is a vector space over $K$ an $U,W$ are subspaces of $V$. Sorry for that

Comment: What's the relation between $\;Z, U, W,...\;$ ?

Comment: OK, I think now is good

Comment: Can we assume $V$ is of finite dimension?

Comment: yes we can assume that

Comment: The statement as you wrote it, is incorrect, take $V=U$ and $W=Z=0$. If $V=U\neq 0$ you can't map $U$ into $W=0$ injectively. Maybe you want $f\colon V\to V$ such that $f(u)=u$ for all $u\in U$ and $f(Z)\subseteq W$? Or maybe you have $V=W\oplus Z=U\oplus Z$?

Comment: nah it's good , for every $\gamma \in Z$ $f(\gamma)=\gamma$ and $f(U) \subseteq W$, ohh rigth direct sum was incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $V$ is of finite dimension $n$, $V=Z\oplus W=Z\oplus U$ and $Z$ is a subspace of dimension $k\le n$, we can conclude that both $W$ and $U$ must be of dimension $n-k$, since $\dim(A\oplus B)=\dim(A)+\dim(B)$. Since all $n-k$ dimensional $k$-vector spaces are isomorphic, there is an isomorphism $\varphi: U\to W$. Now consider the linear map
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{id}_Z \oplus \varphi \colon Z\oplus U &\longrightarrow Z\oplus W, \\
z+u &\longmapsto z+\varphi(u).
\end{align*}

**Edit:** Actually, we don't need finite dimensions to make this work. When $V=Z\oplus W$, the quotient map $V\to V/Z$ restricts to an isomorphism on $W$, so $W\cong V/Z \cong U$, and the above argument works out for arbitrary $k$-vector spaces.

Answer (score 0):

$$V=W\oplus Z\iff\;\;\forall\,v\in B\;\;\exists!(\,w_v\in W,\,z_v\in Z)\;\;s.t. v= w+z$$

Now, just define

$$f(v=w_v+z_v):=z_v = \;\text{ the projection on}\;\;Z$$

Here, $\;f(z)=z\;\;\forall\,z\in Z\;,\;\;f(W)={0}\subset W\;$

Now show the above indeed is a linear transformation.

I'm not sure whether the above is what you wanted since I think there's some confusion with your notation.

Comment: He wants $f(U)\subseteq W$ and $f$ being an isomorphism though.

Comment: He added $\;U\;$ loooong after I posted my answer. It's hard to guess hidden conditions.